# Dividing and retaining the remainder in PHP

Tags: php, divide

I have a number of months (say 38 months).

I need to know how to convert this 38 value to say, 3 years and 2 months.

This is what I have so far:

```
$months = 38;
$years = $months / 12;
```

$years is equal to  3.1666666666667. I am wondering how to be left with simply 3 years, and then the 2 months left over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could calculate the time with the mod operator

```
$months = 38;
$years = floor($months / 12);
$resMonths = $months % 12;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will output “3 years and 2 months”:

```
$months = 38;
print(floor($months/12)." years and ".($months%12)." months");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

```
$months = 38;
$years = floor($months / 12);

//Use modulo to get the remainder
$months = $months % 12;

echo $years . " years and " . $months . " months";
```